# Iterate nested objects using ngFor

Tags: json, angular, object, nested, ngfor

I have JSON object:

```
content = 
[
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"test",
   "parent":{
      "name":"test2",
      "subParent":{
         "name":"test3",
         "subParent":{
            "name":"test4",
            "subParent":{
               "name":"test5",
               "subParent":null
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
]
```

How to iterate through each nested object and display the data in Angular?

I tried to do it with ngFor but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you show your .html please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of content">
    {{data.id}}
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let p of data.parent">
        {{p.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can try something like that, but `recursive templates` is for me, the right way to do that.

Regards,